# Update value based on the previous updated value mysql

Tags: mysql

I looked through the previous topics that may have been related to this and didn't find anything pertaining to what my questions is.

My question is can you update a datetime value in MySql based on the previously updated row? To better explain what I'm wondering here is a pseudo-SQL statement to explain what I'm looking for (no, this is not real SQL):

```
update my_datetime set my_datetime = previously_updated_time + 30 minutes;
```

so the times would go something like this in the update:

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00
1970-01-01 00:30:00
1970-01-02 01:00:00
etc...
```

but accomplishing this all based on the first row updated being the 1970-01-01 00:00:00 value. If it can't be done, I understand but I wanted to see if this would be possible.

Comment: As my prior it can be done using loop but every time executing query definitely crash server.

Comment: What's your PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Mark the last updated record to be able to retrieve it (and unmark all others) - this will work with different increments. If you want to build a table with datetime values for a specific interval, use a tally (number) table (search for it) and build the table using the tally. Sharing your actual goal probably helps us to solve your problem, maybe with a different solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your primary key is `INT` you can do this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET mytable.datetime = mytable.datetime + INTERVAL 30 * mytable.id MINUTE
```

Edit: This works without using primary key:

```
SET @lowest = ( SELECT MIN( datetime ) FROM mytable );

UPDATE mytable
SET mytable.datetime = (@lowest:=@lowest + INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

Comment: OP asks for the last UPDATED, not the last INSERTED row. With updates, there is nothing to do with a numeric primary key in this case. Moreover this solution will work until the first failed insert or the first manual manipulation.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This solution worked great!